# React Redux - Reducer Mutation

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, redux

I have a reducer in which is mutating the state of the current state object by creating a shallow copy. The reducer works by updating a value in a stored object `template` then returning the full state object. The reducer does update the store and i am able to see the change on refresh with the persisted state being regenerated from localStorage. However, components subscribed using `connect()` do not get a re-render. How do i write this reducer the correct way to not mutate the state?

the reducer:

```
case UPDATE_STYLE:
  // Update the style value of the template
  let newState = {
    ...state
  }
  newState
      .templates[action.payload.selectedTemplateType]
      .content[action.payload.selectedTemplate]
      .template
      .styles[action.payload.styleKey][action.payload.fieldKey]
      .value = action.payload.value;

  // mutated state - not firing rerenders
  return newState;
```

firing the dispatch call (works):

```
onStyleChange(styleKey, fieldKey, value){
    this.props.dispatch(
      updateStyle(selectedTemplateType, selectedTemplate, styleKey, fieldKey, value)
    );
  }
```

how the child component is connected (not rendering):

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  templates: state.templates.templates,
  selectedTemplateType: state.templateTypeSelection.selectedTemplateType,
  selectedTemplate: state.templateSelection.selectedTemplate
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Index)
```

Comment: First: You should always return the new state in a immutable way. Usually a reducer is just a function that implements `switch(action.type)` then for each specific action type return a new state(new object) with some changes. Second: If your state is beeing updated correctly the problem could be in your `render()` method, update your question with the component's code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another post already mentioned deep-copy as a quick solution (although you might lose performance). However, even though it's a little tricky, the spread syntax (`...`) might come to your rescue:

```
let newState = { ...state, templates: {
  { ...state.templates, [action.payload.selectedTemplateType]: {
    { ...state.templates[action.payload.selectedTemplateType], content: {
      { ...state.templates[action.payload.selectedTemplateType].content, [ // and so on
```

At least, you'd only create new object for what has actually changed.

On that note: you might want to take a look at immutableJS which provides lots of helpers with this and is less prone to errors. For instance, there is `mergeDeep` to help.

When you don't want to do such a profound transition, there's also deep merge modules on npm (just google for "merge deep npm"); I just didn't actually try any of these...

Comment: I had to make the deep copy this way based on the suggestion here and this post: https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuringreducers/immutableupdatepatterns#common-mistake-2-only-making-a-shallow-copy-of-one-level

Comment: this is indeed good advice and, as said, deep-copying everything is not wrong or faulty - it's just causing updates in parts of the application where no update is necessary as oldState === newState is always false, independently of whether that part changed or not => the link or the posted solution are a little bit better

Answer (score 0):

In your reducer, after the action is handled, the object `state.templateTypeSelection.selectedTemplateType` is the same object, even though some property deep inside the object changed. The other props have the same issue. So, to the component, the props are the same props, therefore the component is not rerendered.

There are a few solutions to this. 1 To flatten your reducer state. (doesn't seem to work for you) 2 To deep copy the reducer state. 3 When you do `mapStateToProps, try to map the innermost property, instead of the top level property.

For solution 2, what you can do is to create classes for the top level property of the reducer state. For example, you can create a class called `TemplateTypeSelection` for `state.templateTyepeSelection`. When you handle the actions in the reducer, for the new state, you use `new TemplateTypeSelection(prevState.templateTypeSelection)` to create a new object for state.templateTypeSelection(You may want to use a constructor to do a shallow copy of the `state.templateTypeSelection`). Since, the state.templateTypeSelection is a new object now, your component should be able to rerender now. The issue with this method is that, since every time you handle an action, you would create a new object, there might be some unnecessary rerender. (This is just an example of how to do it. Prob not a good example, because in your component, you're connecting `state.templateTypeSelection.selectedTemplateType`, not `state.templateTypeSelection`. Hope you get the idea. )

Based on my experience, a combination of method 2 and 3 works best. Also, you may want to consider split the reducer into several reducers.

Comment: I used `TemplateTypeSelection` as an example, but actually, in your project, you're connecting `state.templateTypeSelection.selectedTemplateType`, so you should create a class for `selectedTemplateType`. Your state is way too deep, you might want to consider refactoring it.